# What should be returned when an invalid Web API uri is called?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

1. What should be done if an invalid uri is provided when calling a REST Web API (asp.net mvc)? I'm getting

   HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
   The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.
2. When I provide an invalid controller, I get the following:

   No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
               'http://localhost:51929/api/usera'.
       No type was found that matches the controller named 'usera'.

I thought 1) was the default and ok, but I've been asked to return a custom html page for both of the above and some others errors but it doesn't feel right to return a web page when dealing with an Web API?

1) Is this common practise?

2) Is there a best practice/standard?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a best practice/standard?

One of the important points in HTTP is that the meta data of the response gives general purpose components the hints to support a coarse understanding of what is going on.

One significant piece of meta data is the response code, which communicates when the response body contains a representation of a *resource*, and when instead it contains a representation of "an explanation of the [error situation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)".

Does it have to be a "web page"?  No, of course not.  Instead it could be `text/plain`, or [application/problem+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), or any other representation that you would expect a general purpose client to be able to interpret.

The design of the message should be motivated by its use case, which is to say it is a document intended to be read by a human being trying to figure out what has gone wrong (we don't expect general purpose components to understand how to automatically fix a bad URL; instead, we describe the problem for a person, who will sort it out).